# Can I link my clients model with Django User models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi im new using django and is a little confusing the part of model for my project now.

i need to create a site that user can have their profile and make post of product that they want to offer like a catalog and i'm thinking create this models:

```
class Users_Types(models.Model):

    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_type
        return self.id_type_user

class Users(models.Model):

    users_types= models.OneToOneField('Users_Types')
    e_mail = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.TextField()
    salt = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_user
        return self.id_type_user
        return self.e_mail
        return self.password
        return self.salt

class Clients(models.Model):
    users = models.OneToOneField('Users')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ci = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=)


class products(models.Model):

    clients = models.ForeignKey('clients')
    product = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

but i read about django have it user model, i had to use that model instead that my Users model?

and how i can link the django user model with my clients model.

i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django indeed has it's `User` model and all default authentication is made through that model, and from the start i would strongly recommend you to keep for that default Django `User` model.

And for linking your Client with default user model you need to

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...
```

Reading django docs on [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/) would be very much useful for you.

I think that you know what PEP-8 is, and django has it's kinda same pep: [Coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/), it would help you make your code much cleaner.

Also Django docs has paragraph about referencing to User model: [Referencing the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Django has it's own User built in module.
Just import Users first in your models file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    users_types= models.ForeignKey(User)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.TextField()


class Clients(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ci = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=)
```

You can get user by

```
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

request.user is containing your logged in user.
You can also get you client info by

```
    client_obj = Clients.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Thank you